# How can I search and access data from a widget which is in a map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, flutter, dart

This is my example map:

```js
Map<String, Transaction> _userTransactions = {

   'one': Transaction(amount: - 45, date: DateTime.now(), title: 'socks', accountType: 'timr', notes: 'joa' , icon: Icon(Icons.today,), id: 'kololdcd', repeat: 'always'),
   'two': Transaction(amount: - 60, date: DateTime.now(), title: 'present', accountType: 'timr', notes: 'brother' , icon: Icon(Icons.today,), id: 'kolofkfrcd', repeat: 'never'),
  } ;
```

I want to create a function which calculates the daily balance. Thus I need to identify all Transaction that have a certain value for the argument date (and maybe put them into a new map) Then I need access to the values from the argument amount (from the valid Transaction that we identified before) and add up all values for the daily balance.

I am new to to Futter. I tried to convert the map into a list and used the function .Where to search the date data and access the amount data, but I was confused, because I need access to values from the Widget Transaction which is in a list, which makes the thing a bit more complicated for me.

Do you have any advice how to start or better how to write the whole method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the text of your question and convert it directly into the code you need.

```dart
int getDailyBalance(DateTime targetDate) {
  // (Start with a list of all the values in the map)
  return _userTransactions.values
  // ...identify all Transaction that have a certain value for the argument date
    .where((t) => t.date == targetDate)
  // Then I need access to the values from the argument amount
    .map((t) => t.amount)
  // ...add up all values for the daily balance
    .reduce((a1, a2) => a1 + a2)
  // (Default to zero if no matching values are found [optional])
    ?? 0;;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Abion47. Did you try out the method? Because I copied and paste the code, but getDailyBalance returns null. Does this method work for you?

Comment: @georg I can confirm that [it works for me.](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f4c2080c7c6257016bfba84cc87fd9f6)